# A way to indicate all possible Likert response options for a particular column so that those not used have a 0 by them using pivot longer in R?

Tags: r

I have numerous likert-type questions in my data and am using pivot longer to get percentages of how often each option is used. For some questions, however, certain options are never indicated by a respondent (e.g., they never answered with a 1). However, I would still like to see each possible response for each item with a 0/0% if it wasn't used. For instance, let's say I have a data frame d1.

```
d1(names) 

"Course" "likert_1" "likert_2" "likert_3" "likert_4"
```

```
d1_long <- d1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Course, names_to = "items", values_to = "val") %>% 
  group_by(items) %>% 
  group_by(items, Course) %>% 
  mutate(N= sum (is.na(val) == F),
         val= as.character(val)) %>% 
  group_by(val, .add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            percent = round((n/N), digits = 2)) %>% 
  distinct()
 

head(d1_long)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   items, Course, val [6]
  items             Course      val       n     percent
  <chr>             <chr>       <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
1 likert_1          A765           2         2    0.04
2 likert_1          A765           3         1    0.02
3 likert_1          A765           4         50   0.88
4 likert_1          B768           1         2    0.04
5 likert_1          B768           3         24   0.48
6 likert_1          B768           4         26   0.52
```

So, we can see that response option 1 wasn't used in course "A765", and option 2 wasn't used in course B768. What I am hoping to see is something like this:

```
head(d1_long)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   items, Course, val [6]
  items             Course      val       n     percent
  <chr>             <chr>       <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
1 likert_1          A765           1         0    0.00
2 likert_1          A765           2         2    0.04
3 likert_1          A765           3         1    0.02
4 likert_1          A765           4         50   0.88
4 likert_1          B768           1         2    0.04
5 likert_1          B768           2         0    0.00
6 likert_1          B768           3         24   0.48
```

Any help is greatly appreciated- thanks!

Edited:

```
dput(d1_long)
structure(list(items = c("likert_1", "likert_1", "likert_1", 
"likert_1", "likert_1", "likert_1"), Course = c("A765", "A765", 
"A765", "B768", "B768", "B768"), val = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L), n = c(2L, 1L, 50L, 2L, 24L, 26L), percent = c(0.04, 0.02, 
0.88, 0.04, 0.48, 0.52)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    items = c("likert_1", "likert_1", "likert_1", "likert_1", 
    "likert_1", "likert_1"), Course = c("A765", "A765", "A765", 
    "B768", "B768", "B768"), val = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Edit 2: I should have noted -- not all items have the same response scheme. For instance, some are 1-5 others are 1-7. Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(d1_long))`? The problem in copying the posted table is in the group attribute.

Comment: In reality my dataset is much larger than the one I created for this question. I will work editing in a bit. thanks

Comment: The first 6 rows are enough, that's what `head` will give, so just `dput(head(d1_long))` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. Group by `items` and `Course`, then `complete` based on a vector of all possible responses. Columns `n` and `percent` are filled with zeros (the default is `NA`).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

all_possible_resp <- 1:4

d1_long %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(items, Course) %>% 
  complete(val = all_possible_resp, 
           fill = list(n = 0, percent = 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   items    Course   val     n percent
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <int> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 likert_1 A765       1     0    0   
#> 2 likert_1 A765       2     2    0.04
#> 3 likert_1 A765       3     1    0.02
#> 4 likert_1 A765       4    50    0.88
#> 5 likert_1 B768       1     2    0.04
#> 6 likert_1 B768       2     0    0   
#> 7 likert_1 B768       3    24    0.48
#> 8 likert_1 B768       4    26    0.52
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>